# Swap function in x86-64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to write a function of the form:

> void swap(int *a, int *b);

in x86-64 assembly.

```
[section .text]
global  swap ;
swap: mov ecx, [esp+8] ; copy parameter a to ecx
mov edx, [esp+16] ; copy parameter b to edx
mov eax, [ecx] ; copy a into eax
xchg eax, [edx] ; exchange eax with b
mov [ecx], eax;
ret;
```

I compile this on Linux using the following command:

> ```
> nasm -f elf64 swap.asm
> ```

It compiles without any error. The main file is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 extern void swap(int *a,int *b);
 int main(){
          int a = 10, int b = 20;
          swap(&a,&b);
          printf("a = %d b = %d\n",a,b );
          return 0;
 }
```

The main file also compiles. However, I get a segmentation fault when I run this program. Any ideas where I am making a mistake?

Comment: You should specify the OS/calling convention that you're using. There are a few common x86-64 calling conventions.

Comment: Please write a MRE.

Comment: @Acorn Please check the example I added.

Comment: Don't use XCHG with a memory operand unless you need it to be an atomic operation.  XCHG has implicit LOCK semantics which it make much, much, slower than swapping via temporary registers.

Comment: You say you’re writing 64-bit code, but you’re using 32-bit pointers.

Comment: There’s absolutely no reason to write this in assembly.

Comment: @prl: At least it's stand-alone, not inline, which is a good choice if you're trying to *learn* asm.  Which I assume is the case, given the beginner mistakes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: You're expecting the wrong calling convention. You're also using 32-bit pointers instead of 64-bit ones.

---

Linux x86-64 applications use the System V AMD64 ABI, which has the first 6 "regular" arguments passed in the registers `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8`, `R9`. On entry, `a` is in `RDI`, and `b` is in `RSI`.

In the case of your `swap`, this simplifies your code because you don't need to load from offsets from the stack pointer.

---

```
swap:
    mov eax, [rdi]    ; *a to EAX
    xchg eax, [rsi]   ; Exchange *a with *b
    mov [rdi], eax    ; EAX to *a
    ret
```

---

Note that this isn't necessarily the most effective method for a swap, at a low level. Even though it's fewer instructions, this isn't necessarily better, and is much worse performance-wise. [GCC 10 for x86-64](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:14,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:14,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:14,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:14,startLineNumber:4),source:%27void+swap(int+*a,+int+*b)+%7B%0A++++int+tmp+%3D+*b%3B%0A++++*b+%3D+*a%3B%0A++++*a+%3D+tmp%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:40.74983628028814,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%270%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:38.58150195702167,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),k:20.668661762690178,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) generates loads to registers, then stores with the two flipped.

Comment: Worth pointing out *why* it's disastrously slow: `xchg` with memory has an implicit `lock` prefix, so it's an atomic swap with a full memory barrier.